# Displaying text at the top of cells using parbox

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment

I use the following command `\multirow{5}{*}{\parbox[t]{2cm}{\raggedright$a1=0.12$; $a2=-0.14$; $a3=0.2$}}` to display the text at the top of a cell.

Unfortunately, it doesn't work.

How to correct it? I posted the following codes for your reference:

```
\documentclass[[preprint,11pt,authoryear]{elsarticle}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{rotating,array,booktabs}
\usepackage[skip=0.333\baselineskip]{caption}
        \begin{sidewaystable}[h]
            \captionsetup{font=footnotesize}
            \caption{Comparsion of Methods}\label{tab:LPer}

            \footnotesize
            \setlength\tabcolsep{0pt} % let LaTeX determine intercol. whitespace 
            \setlength\extrarowheight{1pt}
           % \begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{>{\raggedright}p{2cm}
            \begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{p{2cm}
                @{\extracolsep{\fill}} cc*{6}{ccc}} % 21 [!] columns in all
            \toprule

            Model \& Parameters & Input 1 & Input 2 
            &\multicolumn{3}{c}{M0} &\multicolumn{3}{c}{M1} 
            &\multicolumn{3}{c}{M2} &\multicolumn{3}{c}{M3}
            &\multicolumn{3}{c}{M4} &\multicolumn{3}{c}{M5}\\ 
            \cmidrule{4-6}   \cmidrule{7-9} 
            \cmidrule{10-12} \cmidrule{13-15} 
            \cmidrule{16-18} \cmidrule{19-21} 
            &&
            & $N$ & error& Time & $N$ & error & Time & $N$ & error& Time & $N$ & error& Time & $N$ & error & Time & $N$ & error& Time \\
            \midrule
           \multirow{5}{*}{\parbox[t]{2cm}{\raggedright$a3=0.12$; $a2=-0.14$; $a1=0.2$}} & $\theta$   &  1--100& $N$ & error& Time & $N$ & error & Time & $N$ & error& Time& $N$ & error& Time & $N$ & error & Time & $N$ & error& Time  \\


            &&&$N$ & error& Time & $N$ & error & Time & $N$ & error& Time& $N$ & error& Time & $N$ & error & Time & $N$ & error& Time  \\
            &&&$N$ & error& Time & $N$ & error & Time & $N$ & error& Time & $N$ & error& Time & $N$ & error & Time & $N$ & error& Time \\
            &&&$N$ & error& Time & $N$ & error & Time & $N$ & error& Time& $N$ & error& Time & $N$ & error & Time & $N$ & error& Time \\
            &&&$N$ & error& Time & $N$ & error & Time & $N$ & error& Time& $N$ & error& Time & $N$ & error & Time & $N$ & error& Time  \\



\bottomrule
   \end{tabular*}
   \end{sidewaystable}
   \end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! `\begin{document}` after `\usepackage[skip=0.333\baselineskip]{caption}` is missing.

Answer (score 1):

When you say `\multirow{5}{*}{..}`, the text inside will be vertically centered relative to the next `five` rows. However, your text inside `multirow` is worth only `three` rows, so just remove `5` and put `3`. I also improved the first cell. I advise you, though, to re-think the design of the whole table in a normal orientation, I may suggest something for you in a while.

```
\documentclass[preprint,11pt,authoryear]{elsarticle}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{rotating,array,booktabs}
\usepackage[skip=0.333\baselineskip]{caption}
\begin{document}
        \begin{sidewaystable}
            \captionsetup{font=footnotesize}
            \caption{Comparsion of Methods}\label{tab:LPer}

            \footnotesize
            \setlength\tabcolsep{0pt} % let LaTeX determine intercol. whitespace 
            \setlength\extrarowheight{1pt}
           % \begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{>{\raggedright}p{2cm}
            \begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{l
                @{\extracolsep{\fill}} cc*{6}{ccc}} % 21 [!] columns in all
            \toprule

            Model \&  & Input 1 & Input 2 
            &\multicolumn{3}{c}{M0} &\multicolumn{3}{c}{M1} 
            &\multicolumn{3}{c}{M2} &\multicolumn{3}{c}{M3}
            &\multicolumn{3}{c}{M4} &\multicolumn{3}{c}{M5}\\ 
            Parameters & & & & & \\ 
            \cmidrule{4-6}   \cmidrule{7-9} 
            \cmidrule{10-12} \cmidrule{13-15} 
            \cmidrule{16-18} \cmidrule{19-21} 
            &&
            & $N$ & error& Time & $N$ & error & Time & $N$ & error& Time & $N$ & error& Time & $N$ & error & Time & $N$ & error& Time \\
            \midrule
           \multirow{3}{*}{\begin{tabular}{l}$a3=0.12$;\\$a2=-0.14$;\\$a1=0.2$\end{tabular}} & $\theta$   &  1--100& $N$ & error& Time & $N$ & error & Time & $N$ & error& Time& $N$ & error& Time & $N$ & error & Time & $N$ & error& Time  \\


            &&&$N$ & error& Time & $N$ & error & Time & $N$ & error& Time& $N$ & error& Time & $N$ & error & Time & $N$ & error& Time  \\
            &&&$N$ & error& Time & $N$ & error & Time & $N$ & error& Time & $N$ & error& Time & $N$ & error & Time & $N$ & error& Time \\
            &&&$N$ & error& Time & $N$ & error & Time & $N$ & error& Time& $N$ & error& Time & $N$ & error & Time & $N$ & error& Time \\
            &&&$N$ & error& Time & $N$ & error & Time & $N$ & error& Time& $N$ & error& Time & $N$ & error & Time & $N$ & error& Time  \\   
\bottomrule
   \end{tabular*}
   \end{sidewaystable}
   \end{document}
```

[image]

Now, see the following design (only 7 cols and you saved the energy of your readers keeping their heads up):

```
\begin{table}
\centering
\caption{Comparsion of Methods}\label{tab:LPer}
\begin{tabular}{@{}ll *5{c}@{}}
\toprule
Parameters
& Model &  Input 1 &  Input 2 & $N$ & Error & Time \\ \midrule
&       &          &          & $N$ & Error & Time \\
&       &          &          & $N$ & Error & Time \\
& $M_0$ & $\theta$ &  1--100  & $N$ & Error & Time \\
&       &          &          & $N$ & Error & Time \\
&       &          &          & $N$ & Error & Time \\ \cmidrule{2-7}
&       &          &          & $N$ & Error & Time \\
&       &          &          & $N$ & Error & Time \\
& $M_1$ & $\theta$ &  1--100  & $N$ & Error & Time \\
&       &          &          & $N$ & Error & Time \\
&       &          &          & $N$ & Error & Time \\ \cmidrule{2-7}
&       &          &          & $N$ & Error & Time \\
&       &          &          & $N$ & Error & Time \\
& $M_2$ & $\theta$ &  1--100  & $N$ & Error & Time \\
&       &          &          & $N$ & Error & Time \\
\multirow{3}{*}[5pt]{\begin{tabular}{l}$a3=0.12$;\\$a2=-0.14$;\\$a1=0.2$\end{tabular}}
&       &          &          & $N$ & Error & Time \\ \cmidrule{2-7}
&       &          &          & $N$ & Error & Time \\
&       &          &          & $N$ & Error & Time \\
& $M_3$ & $\theta$ &  1--100  & $N$ & Error & Time \\
&       &          &          & $N$ & Error & Time \\
&       &          &          & $N$ & Error & Time \\ \cmidrule{2-7}
&       &          &          & $N$ & Error & Time \\
&       &          &          & $N$ & Error & Time \\
& $M_4$ & $\theta$ &  1--100  & $N$ & Error & Time \\
&       &          &          & $N$ & Error & Time \\
&       &          &          & $N$ & Error & Time \\ \cmidrule{2-7}
&       &          &          & $N$ & Error & Time \\
&       &          &          & $N$ & Error & Time \\
& $M_5$ & $\theta$ &  1--100  & $N$ & Error & Time \\
&       &          &          & $N$ & Error & Time \\
&       &          &          & $N$ & Error & Time \\ \bottomrule
\end{tabular}   
\end{table}
```

with this "nice" output (you may also want to shift the `$M_n$ \theta 1--100` rows two rows up):

> [image]